# cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.tasks.task<Quartz.Scheduler> to <Quartz.IScheduler>

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz

```
public void Start()
    {

        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new  StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x

              .WithIntervalInHours(48)
              .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

I'm getting error in `IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();`

It says

> "cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.tasks.task
>   Quartz.Scheduler to Quartz.IScheduler"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437430/quartz-net-error-comes-every-time-i-use-it

Comment: please look into the above link.

Comment: Okey. Thanks I'm looking right now. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz.NET error comes every time I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437430/quartz-net-error-comes-every-time-i-use-it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`schedFact.GetScheduler();` returns `Task` You should use the following code to get `IScheduler` object:

```
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```